# Excel Min/Max on subset within range of values

Tags: excel, max, min

I have a excel sheet containing two columns of data, I need formulae that will return the min&max value in column2 where value in column1 is within a range (given date)

ie for 03/04/2013 min would be 428.80, max would be 431.40

```
Date&Time               Value
===================     ======
02/04/2013 10:15:05     429.10
02/04/2013 12:37:42     429.30
03/04/2013 15:45:00     430.50
03/04/2013 15:50:00     429.70
03/04/2013 15:55:00     428.80    <== Min
03/04/2013 16:00:00     429.40
03/04/2013 16:05:00     429.50
03/04/2013 16:10:00     429.60
03/04/2013 16:15:00     429.80    <== Max
03/04/2013 16:20:00     429.60
03/04/2013 16:25:00     430.40
03/04/2013 16:50:12     431.40
03/04/2013 17:10:01     429.60
04/04/2013 08:20:00     431.88
04/04/2013 08:25:00     431.70
04/04/2013 08:30:00     431.30
04/04/2013 08:35:00     430.90
04/04/2013 08:40:00     430.70
04/04/2013 08:45:00     429.90
04/04/2013 08:50:00     429.10
04/04/2013 09:00:00     429.50
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? And, are you looking for a way to do this on the worksheet or with code/VBA?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your date is in column A and values are all positive and is in column B, create column C which contains 1 if A is in range and 0 is not in range. Then create column D which has formula =B2*C2 and find =max(D:D) for maximum among selected
For minimum, put formula =C2/B2 in column E, and calculate minimum among selected as =1/max(E:E)

Answer (score 1):

If your date criteria, e.g. 03/04/2013 is in D2 then with date/time values in A2:A100 and numeric values in B2:B100 you can use an "array formula" like this in E2

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(INT(A$2:A$100)=D2,B$2:B$100),1),"No match")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> so that curly braces like { and } appear automatically around the formula

that gives the MIN value, replace SMALL with LARGE for MAX value

Comment: Barry, this is really cool. I only wish I had the ability to mark your reply as an acceptable answer. This works great. I do have one question. Why the curly braces? I see that they are required to make the formula work, but what's special about this formula that makes them required? – Karl just now edit